# Wave Equation in PDE form

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What is the PDE form for a travelling pulse with Dirichlet boundary condition, but the initial condition doesnt split into two waves ? what i mean is not of the form : $$ u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}, \:\:\: with $$ $$\:\: u_{t}(x,0) = g(x), \: u(x,0) = f(x),$$ and the Dirichlet boundary condition of course. The PDE form is that the solution would look like this animation :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wave_equation_1D_fixed_endpoints.gif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the MATLAB code on the page to which you linked, you'll see the answer to your question.

The PDE used there is the ordinary wave equation  $u_{tt}=c^2 u_{xx}$. For computational purposes it is discretized as

```
for i=2:(N-1)
     U(i) = (c*tau/h)^2*(U1(i+1)-2*U1(i)+U1(i-1)) + 2*U1(i) - U0(i);
end
```

The traveling wave results if we set the initial velocity to $g(x)=-c f'(x)$. Indeed, the solution with this initial velocity is $u(x,t)=f(x-ct)$, which is easy to check.

The "initial condition split into two waves" scenario occurs when $g=0$; it's the effect of initial condition, not of the PDE.